# Не могу понять почему не работает условие?

Tags: python

Я парсю с помощью библиотеки feedparser RSS ленту [этого ресурса](http://lenta.crimea.ua/rss/news) .После записываю результат в БД.
У меня выходит такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\feedparser.py", line 398, in __getattr__
    return self.__getitem__(key)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\feedparser.py", line 356, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
KeyError: 'published'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users=PycharmProjects/parser_russian_resource/parser_rss.py", line 61, in <module>
    call_all_func(resources)
  File "C:/UsersPycharmProjects/parser_russian_resource/parser_rss.py", line 40, in call_all_func
    rss_published = feed.published
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\feedparser.py", line 400, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("object has no attribute '%s'" % key)
AttributeError: object has no attribute 'published'
```

Я понимаю что эта ошибка значит.Она значит что я использую не тот key. И в следствии код обваливается.
И вот чтобы все работало решил сделать условие.

То есть,если ключ published не подходит.Использовать ключ updated а если не подходит ключ updated.Использовать ключ pubdate.
Вот для этой цели написал такой код:

```
rss_published = feed.published

            if rss_published != feed.published:
                rss_published = feed.updated
            else:
                rss_published = feed.pubdate
```

И вот я не могу понять.Почему условие не работает?

Comment: Условие не работает, потому что ошибка возникнет уже на строчке `rss_published = feed.published`. Смотрите документацию по feedparser - возможно есть какие-то штатные методы проверки, есть ли во внутреннем дикте нужный ключ. Если нет - делайте обработку исключения `KeyError` через try-except.

Comment: @insolor,хорошо ! Благодарю вас за инфу.Теперь будет где копать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как мне подсказали выше в комментарии.Я решил делать проверку исключения

```
                try:
                    rss_published = feed.updated
                except (KeyError,AttributeError):
                    rss_published = feed.pubdate
                    rss_published = feed.published
```